# Error: Trying to requery an already closed cursor

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I'm running into an error but I can't seem to find a solution. My application is working on ICS 4.0.3 but it returns the error on Android 3.2. Here is the code in my `MainActivity.java` file:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
         Cursor cursor = db.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"_id","isim","icerik"}, null, null, null, null, null);
         startManagingCursor(cursor);
         tts=0;



         while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            if(tts==0)
             {            
            array_spinner=new String[cursor.getCount()+1];
            array_spinner[tts]= "FAVORİ";
             }
            array_spinner2[tts+1]= cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex("isim")));
            array_spinner3[tts+1]= cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex("icerik")));
             tts++;
            } 

         ss2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
         ArrayAdapter<Object> adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this,R.layout.row2, R.id.weekofday2, array_spinner2);
            ss2.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Somewhere, you are closing the `Cursor` you are passing to `startManagingCursor()`. Call `stopManagingCursor()` before closing the `Cursor`.

Note that `startManagingCursor()` is deprecated. Instead of using that, when your data changes, run another query in the background (e.g., `AsyncTask`, `CursorLoader`).

Also, you might consider using a `CursorAdapter`, like `SimpleCursorAdapter`, rather than manually converting all of the data into objects and using an `ArrayAdapter`.

Also, if you are going to use `ArrayAdapter`, please declare it with a more concrete class (e.g., `ArrayAdapter<String>`, not `ArrayAdapter<Object>`.

Comment: This error exists when am using **CursorAdapter**. For me its different scenario. I have run the app and press **Home** button and again run my app using recent apps this exception will thrown. I think better way to do this use *CursorLoader*

Comment: Calling `stopManagingCursor` before closing the `Cursor` fixed the error for me! Thanks @CommonsWare

Answer (score 2):

put this it may work for you:

```
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestart();

        cursor.requery();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This error seems to be caused by inaccurate usage of deprecated method

```
startManagingCursor()
```

Can't be 100% sure that properly called `stopManagingCursor()` will solve the issue because it is very occasional.

I would recommend to avoid using it and stick with CursorLoader and LoaderManager.